# UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to update column named `count` in my BigQuery table `table_A` by comparing it against my table `table_B`.

For every row, if the values of `count` don´t match between tables, I want to update the `table_A.count` with `table_B.count`. But I am getting the following error: `UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row`. This is probably because I am trying to update multiple rows at a time.

Here´s how my query looks like:

```
UPDATE 
  table_A AS prod_table
SET 
  prod_table.count = table_B.count 
FROM 
  table_A AS table_A 

  LEFT JOIN table_B 
  ON table_A.Date = table_B.Date 
  
  AND table_A.Name = table_B.Name 
  AND table_A.count <> table_B.count 
WHERE 
  table_B.count IS NOT NULL 
  AND table_A.Date = table_B.Date 
  AND table_A.Name = table_B.Name
```

How can I modify my query to update all rows at the same time? I would appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want:

```
UPDATE table_A a
    SET count = b.count 
    FROM table_B b
    WHERE a.Date = a.Date AND  
         a.Name = b.Name AND
         a.count <> b.count ;
```